# Custom loss function: Apply weights to binary cross-entropy error

Tags: keras

I am playing around with Keras and try to predict a word from within a context e.g. from a sentence "*I have to say the food was tasty!*" I hope to get something like this:

```
[say the ? was tasty] -> food, meals, spaghetti, drinks
```

However, my problem currently is that the network I am training appears to learn just the probabilities of the single words, and not the probabilities they have in a particular context.

Since the frequency of words is not balanced I thought I might/could/should apply weights to my loss function - which is currently the binary-cross entropy function.

I simply multiply the converse probability of each word with the error:

```py
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true) * (1-word_weights), axis=1)
```

This function is being used by the model as loss function:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=weighted_binary_crossentropy)
```

However, my results are the exact same and I am not sure if just my model is broken or if I am using the `loss` paramter/function wrong.

is my `weighted_binary_crossentropy()` function doing what I just described? I asked because for some reason this works similar:
word_weights), axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as one may read in a [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) of a `fit` function, one may provide `sample_weights` which seem to be exactly what you want use.

Comment: It says "*if you need to do timestep-wise sample weighting (2D weights), set this to "temporal". "None" defaults to sample-wise weights (1D).*" which really does not sound to me as if it would weight the error for each output dimension - because this is what I'd like to do.

Comment: Are this weights you want to apply are different for each word?